# Threading help needed

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

Any ideas on how to get this code to work?
I am using windows 7 and python 3.3.2

```
from tkinter import *

class Clock:
def _init_(self, parent):
    self.parent = parent
    self.x = 0
    self.y = 0
    self.second = Label(parent)
    self.minute = Label(parent)
    self.second.pack()
    self.minute.pack()
def advance(self):
    self.second.config(text = "{0.x} second(s)".format(self))
    self.minute.config(text = "{0.z} minute(s) has past".format(self))
    self.x += 1
    if self.x == 60:
        self.x = 0
        self.z += 1
    self.parent.after(1000, self.advance)


mGui = Tk()
mGui.geometry("300x200+100+100")
mGui.title("Jono's Clock")

clock = Clock(mGui)

menubar = Menu(mGui)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Clock", command = clock.advance)

menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
mGui.config(menu = menubar)

mGui.mainloop()
```

Error is same as I stated in comment.

Any amount of help is appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: Please explain the problem you are experiencing. We are not clairvoyants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need thread here. Use [`after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) function if you want periodically excute something.

```
from tkinter import *

class Clock:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.x = 0
        self.z = 0
        self.second = Label(parent)
        self.minute = Label(parent)
        self.second.pack()
        self.minute.pack()
    def advance(self):
        self.second.config(text='{0.x} second(s)'.format(self))
        self.minute.config(text='{0.z} minute(s) past.'.format(self))
        self.x += 1
        if self.x == 60:
            self.x = 0
            self.z += 1
        self.parent.after(1000, self.advance)
        # This method is called after 1000 ms (1 second)

mGui = Tk()
mGui.geometry("300x200+100+100")
mGui.title("Jono's Clock")

clock = Clock(mGui)


menubar = Menu(mGui)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Clock", command=clock.advance)

menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
mGui.config(menu = menubar)

mGui.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Minigeek22, What does it mean `gggggggggggggggg` ?

Comment: Sorry keyboard messed up "gggggggggggggggg"

Comment: @Minigeek22, It works perfectly in my system (Python 3.3.2, Windows 7 64bit). Please give me exact traceback instead of just saying `i get an error` ;)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kids\Desktop\Python Tests\Clock2.py", line 27, in <module>
    clock = Clock(mGui)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters